# D3: Cannot add text element to graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Everything seems to be working as expected except for the text element. I can't seem to get text elements to append to my g element. Here is my code so far. I've inspected the DOM in a chrome browser, but I don't see any text elements and I'm not sure why. I was using this site as a sort of guide: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element.

Also, I know the elements should stack on each other since they all share the same x and y position, I'm just trying to get the elements to appear first.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg'),
margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 45, left: 60},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
x.domain(test.map(function(d) { return d.level; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(test, function(d) { return d.time; })]);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("writing-mode", "tb-rl")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0).tickPadding(10));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency")

g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(test)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.level); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.time); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.time); })

var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(test).enter()
    .append("text");

var textLabels =    text.attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .text("testing")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your selection `g.selectAll("text")` will include text from the axes you appended to the g element earlier in the code, so your "enter" won't have anything in it. D3 compares the incoming to data to the items in the selection, and if you don't specify a key, will do a simple comparison on the number of elements in each, and then add (enter) and remove (exit) accordingly.

If you change your selection to something that you know won't be on in DOM yet (ie an empty selection), for example `g.selectAll(".label")`, then when you append data, the enter selection will contain your new text labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation it was really helpful.